# Make Counter consider two objects of the same class the same

Tags: python, data-structures, collections

I'm using collections.Counter. It's great so far, except that I'd like it to count objects of the same class as the same. How can I do this? I tried overriding the **hash**() method on the class so that all instances would hash the same. Right now, if I do `Counter([Type1(), Type1(), Type2(), Type2()])` it will return `{<Type1 object at...>:1,<Type1 object at...>:1,<Type2 object at...>:1,<Type2 object at...>:1}` I would prefer it to return something like `{"Type1":2, "Type2":2}` instead. Is this possible? I was poking around the docs and couldn't figure out how to make it work.

I should add that the classes I'm using are essentially wrappers for constant values. It's just more convenient to wrap them in a class. Under no circumstances will one Type1 object ever differ from another Type1 object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having read your question again, I'm adding a different approach which might be more suitable to your needs.

A Counter is a dictionary, and dictionaries in Python use the `__hash__` method and the `__eq__` method to compare objects.  So you need to define these two methods if you want objects which always compare equal and can be used as dictionary keys.

```
# (Python 3)
class Type1:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Type1):
            return True
        return super().__eq__(other)

    def __hash__(self):
        return 1329916036    # anything constant
```

If you do the same for `Type2`, you can count instances in a `Counter` like this:

```
>>> mycounter = Counter([Type1(), Type1(), Type2(), Type2()])
>>> mycounter
Counter({<__main__.Type1 object at ...>: 2, <__main__.Type2 object at ...>: 2})
>>> mycounter[Type1()]
2
```

Comment: Ah, eq, that's what I was missing. Thank you. I actually think the approach you suggested works better for my particular situation, though this is what I was asking for!

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
Counter(type(x) for x in [Type1(), Type1(), Type2(), Type2()])
```

This is how you would use it:

```
>>> type_counter = Counter(type(x) for x in [Type1(), Type1(), Type2(), Type2()])
>>> type_counter
Counter({<class '__main__.Type2'>: 2, <class '__main__.Type1'>: 2})
>>> type_counter[Type1]
2
>>> type_counter[type(Type2())]
2
```

Comment: This is the best way. Classes can be used as dictionary keys!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group them by class name, you can use the `__name__` attribute:

```
Counter(i.__name__ for i in (Type1(), Type2(), Type1()))
```

Or:

```
from operator import attrgetter

Counter(map(attrgetter('__name__'), (Type1(), Type2(), Type1())))
```